# javascript passing the class index on a function call

Tags: javascript, function, class, arguments

hi guys I need to know how do I pass the class index to a function when calling it.

let's say I have 3 input tags like this one:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="email" class="PIC" 
onchange="val(this.getAttribute('class'), **index0**)" />
<input type="text" placeholder="email" class="PIC" 
onchange="val(this.getAttribute('class'), **index1**)" />
<input type="text" placeholder="email" class="PIC" 
onchange="val(this.getAttribute('class'), **index2**)" />
```

Now what i want to do is just like i passed in the class name i want to pass in the class index which the function got called from. index0 should pass in a 0 index1 1 should pass in 1 and so on...

lets say the function val is this:

```
function val(className, Index) {
  alert('class is ' + className + ' and the index is: ' + index);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by class index?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an event listener in JavaScript. I kept it as a `change` event though you may find the `input` event to be a better fit.

I also added a val function that logs the information since one was not provided.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.PIC').forEach(function(ele, index) {
      ele.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        let myClass = ele.getAttribute('class')
        val(myClass, index);
      });
    });

function val(eleClass, eleIndex) {
console.log(eleClass, eleIndex);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="email" class="PIC" />
<input type="text" placeholder="email" class="PIC" />
<input type="text" placeholder="email" class="PIC" />
```

Comment: @BenGababy I know? What's the problem?

Comment: It's for learning purpose only. Is there a way to keep it as i did it with just passing the class indez just as I passed in the class name. I am just learning javascript I still don't understand complicated code. thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @BenGababy no there isn't a way to pass in an index implicitly in markup. You either need to explicitly declare it within the invocation for each element that is going to call the function, add an event listener through code beforehand, or figure it out when the function runs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".PIC").forEach(function(input, index){
        input.onchange = val(input.getAttribute('class'), index);
    })
```